# Is there a way to determine to which etcd host the kubernetes apiserver is talking to?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, etcd3

Only apiserver talks directly to etcd. In the etcd cluster there are many hosts.  I would like to see to which etcd host the apiserver is talking to. This may be different for each api resource like Pod or Node. I prefer to see etcd host information for each request.

Specifically, kubernetes 1.6.13 and etcd 3.1.14 using v3 store.

I have tried:

1. Enable etcd client and grpc logging on the kubernetnes api server.

   I think grpc only logs in unexpected events. Similarly for etcd 
   clientv3. I was not able to get information about the etcd side of the 
   connection.
2. Enable http2 debug logging with `GODEBUG=http2debug=2` on api server

   To my surprise http2 debug logs print a lot of information about each request but I  could not find the remote endpoint information. I am still skeptical about this I may be missing a mention in the log files. Not completely sure.
3. Debug logs on the etcd side.

   Enabling debug logs with [Enabling Debug Logging](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/v2/admin_guide.html) prints only about v2 store accesses. For v3 store [one could use the](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/8418#issuecomment-323440622) `http://<host>2379/debug/requests` endpoint but that is not available in my version of etcd 3.1.14.
4. I have not tried yet to use `GODEBUG=http2debug=2` on the etcd side. Maybe the http2 logs on the etcd have the info I need.
5. `tcpdump` or `tcpflow`

   The apiserver <-> etcd connection is encrypted. Would these show me the request url ? I *think* I did not see that information in the dumps.
6. Man in the middle attack the apiserver <-> etcd connection with [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). I do not think this should be that complicated.

I hope,  I have missed  a super obvious and simple way to accomplish this.

---

**Update:**

About using `lsof` based approaches:

Using `lsof`, we can list the connections with endpoints information at one time. I do not think there is enough information in `lsof` output to arrive at endpoint information per request. Apiserver opens a lot of connections to etcd. Looking at the code that observation looks reasonable to me. See `NewStorage` in [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/14ea65f53cdae4a5657cf38cfc8d7349b75b5512/pkg/registry/core/rest/storage_core.go#L133)

```
$ sudo lsof -p 20816 | grep :2379  | wc -l
130
```

The connections looks like this

$ sudo lsof -

```
p 20816 | grep :2379  | head -n 5
hyperkube 20816 root    3u     IPv4 58093240        0t0        TCP compute-master7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:36360->compute-etcd7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:2379 (ESTABLISHED)
hyperkube 20816 root    5u     IPv4 58085987        0t0        TCP compute-master7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:26005->compute-etcd7002.dsv31.boxdc.net:2379 (ESTABLISHED)
hyperkube 20816 root    6u     IPv4 58085988        0t0        TCP compute-master7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:55650->compute-etcd7003.dsv31.boxdc.net:2379 (ESTABLISHED)
hyperkube 20816 root    7u     IPv4 58102030        0t0        TCP compute-master7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:36366->compute-etcd7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:2379 (ESTABLISHED)
hyperkube 20816 root    8u     IPv4 58085990        0t0        TCP compute-master7001.dsv31.boxdc.net:55654->compute-etcd7003.dsv31.boxdc.net:2379 (ESTABLISHED)
........
```

Looking at this, I cannot know which etcd is used for each request between the apiserver and etcd.

---

**Update:**

I think at the etcdv3 client code that ships with kubernetes 1.6.13, the `grpc.Balancer.Get` function returns the endpoint address used for each grpc request. I *think* one could add a log print [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/14ea65f53cdae4a5657cf38cfc8d7349b75b5512/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3/balancer.go#L136) and make apiserver log the etcd address per request.

Answer (score 0):

Find the pid of apiserver

`ps aux | grep apiserver`

Then use `lsof` to see the open socket connections

`lsof -p $PID | grep :2379`

Comment: I do not think there is enough information in `lsof` output. Updated my question accordingly.